# How to open Model in View from Server

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have a View which has a button. When the button is a Model opens with a form 
on it which has some inputs. So the user make his input and then submit the file so that it can be saved in a database. This all works fine.
I now want to test if the input was correct. If not I want the same Model to open just with the error message from the viewbag. 
So my question is how to open the model on the view directly when the page is loaded if the viewbag contains a message.

Comment: Please read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and update your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with an if statement in jquery where I checked if the error 
div contains html. if it does when I open my view it also opens my model.